# Adding rows to a JTable

Tags: java, swing

We have a simple project where we read data from a socket and we want to populate a table with the coming data, but we can't find a way to add rows to a yet created `JTable` object, we can only find how to add rows at creation time of the table.

Is it possible to add rows dynamically to a `JTable`, or there is a better alternative object to deal with this way of showing data?

**EDIT**: Thanks a lot for your answers.

All three of them look very promising, but I have to choose only one and I think the best is Guillaume's.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should create a custom [`TableModel`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html). A `JTable` doesn't actually store the rows, it always delegates that to a `TableModel`. To help you implementing it, you should make use of [`AbstractTableModel`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html). Don't forget to call [`fireTableRowsInserted()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsInserted(int,%20int)) every time you add rows. For better performances if you add a lot of rows, try to batch the updates and add many rows at a time.

Answer (score 11):

If you use the default table model for a  JTable then you can add rows with following code

```
 if ( dest+1 < table.getRowCount()-1 )
    ( (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel() ).insertRow(dest+1, getValuesForNewRow());
  else
    ( (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel() ).addRow(getValuesForNewRow());
```

Comment: It's best to just keep hold of the DefaultTableModel before passing it to the JTable constructor. Then you don't need to touch the JTable or do any casting.

Answer (score 6):

Once you start dynamically adding and removing elements from a JTable, you really need to start using a TableModel.

See the [Java Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details.