# How to add new row in jtable while click a button

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding rows to a JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295649/adding-rows-to-a-jtable)

I am creating a jTable. Initially it has no rows.If we click "add" button  a new row will insert.Is it possible to do this in a jTable?

Comment: yes, its possible but without SSCCE we cant help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your underlying `TableModel` and fire the appropriate event. Or, if you use an extension of `DefaultTableModel`, use the [`addRow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method.

Consult the [table tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information.