# Database into JTable

Tags: java, database, jtable

I want to add data from `MySql` into `JTable`. I just write this simple code to do it, but it's not working.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("user", "root"); 
    props.put("password", "password");  
    props.put("useUnicode", "true"); 
    props.put("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
    props.put("useServerPrepStmts", "false");
    props.put("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/library_System";
    Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
           Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();    

    String SQL = "select * from library_system";

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

model.addColumn("Name");
model.addColumn("Email");

JTable table = new JTable(model);
table.setSize(Int2.getWidth(), Int2.getHeight());
panel3.add(table);

while(rs.next()) 
{ 
    model.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getString("Full_Name"), rs.getString("Email")});
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your query is returning results? Quick way to verify that would be to add a println into your loop.

Comment: yeh,  query is returning results

Comment: can you please add the code of the `ResultSet ` object and the query...

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure, but try to addRow() first.
Create the JTable with the model later.

Answer (score 0):

Always use [fireTableRowsInserted()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsInserted%28int,%20int%29) after adding a  row. Also referee the following link

[Adding rows to a JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295649/adding-rows-to-a-jtable).