# Creating a JTable in Java

Tags: java, swing, multidimensional-array, arraylist, jtable

The data I will be using for the JTable is an ArrayList of object data (e.g. Person) that will be returned using a method. Because the constructor of a JTable requires you to pass in an Object type multi-dimensional array, do I need to convert this ArrayList to a  multi-dimensional array? 
Either case, how can I go about creating a JTable from an ArrayList of Object data?

Thanks much appreciated

Comment: Please read [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) to answer your question.

Comment: I am actually using that Oracle site, but does not deal with ArrayList, as I am. My data is not hard coded, unlike the tutorial. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using `DefaultTableModel` (without requiring multi-dimensional array)

```
String columns = new String[] {"Name", "Age"};
ArrayList<Person> data = getYourData();

DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel(data.size(), columns.length);
JTable table = new JTable(dm);

for(Person p : data) {
   table.addRow(new String[]{p.name, p.age});
}
```

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295649/adding-rows-to-a-jtable) question for additional info

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply. Great solution. Didnt think about it's base class. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

```
you can try this code. And set your JTables model from this method.


public TableModel toTableModel() {
    Object[] headerNames = new Object[] { "a", "b" };
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(headerNames, 0);
    List<String> valueList = new ArrayList<String>();
    valueList.add("a");
    valueList.add("b");
    model.addRow(valueList.toArray());
    return model;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply, didnt think of the base class. Thanks again