# Row not added to JTable in java

Tags: java, database, jtable

I am trying to add rows in `JTable` at run time the data is coming from database successfully but rows are not getting added to `JTable`. I've tried lot of solutions from stackoverflow but I didn't get any success.

Here is my code:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{ "Invoice Number", "Consignee's Name", "Invoice Date", "Amount" }, 0);

void setLabel(String s1,String s2) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You Choose Invoice List of Period "+s1+" to "+s2, "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);   
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/resetdb", "root", ""); 
        java.sql.Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String SQL; 

        SQL="Select * from bill_info where invdt BETWEEN '"+s1+"' AND '"+s2+"'";

        rs =  (ResultSet) stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
        if (rs.next()) {
            rs.beforeFirst();  
            while(rs.next()) {
               count++; 
               String d = rs.getString("invoice");
               String e = rs.getString("Cname");
               String f = rs.getString("invdt");
               String g = rs.getString("Amount");
               model.addRow(new Object[]{ d,e,f,g });
            } 
        } 
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage());
    }         
}
```

The function `setLabel(String s1, String s2)` is called from previous frame where I am passing 2 dates in `String` format as its parameter. My task is to print all invoice data in that selected period.

For checking I tried one more thing.  I added the following lines in my code just before `model.addRow(new Object[]{ d,e,f,g });` to check whether data is retrieved successfully and it is printing data successfully in output:

```
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(f);
System.out.println(g);
```

Comment: where you define `model`?

Comment: This might be helpful [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295649/adding-rows-to-a-jtable)

Comment: At first glance, that looks fine.  Is `model` actually the `TableModel` being used by your `JTable`?  If not, nothing will show up...

Comment: It is also possible the `JTable` layout is being computed when the table is empty, and thus sized to just the header of the table.   Is the `JTable` in a `JScrollPane`, and does that have a minimum size taller than just the header?

Comment: @Jerry06 I declared `model` as global. i have added it now above

Comment: @AJNeufeld Yes you are right by default my `JTable` in empty and `JTable` is in `JScrollPane` but i don't understand the meaning of 'minimum size taller than just the header'. Please can you explain it.

Comment: Spent the last little while playing around with `JTable`, `JScrollPane` and different layouts.  I'm not reproducing a layout issue.  I'm guessing a problem with updating while not on the Event Dispatching Thread (see answer below), or an accident where you've created two table models, one which is installed in your `JTable` (allowing you to see your table column headings) and a separate stand-alone model that rows are being added to.   To debug this further, we'd need to see a [mcve] showing the problem.  Use a fake database query, like in the answer below, and create a minimal GUI.

Comment: @AJNeufeld Accidentally i found one thing that my data is coming to `JTable` row but its not get displayed. I tried `MouseClicked` event on `JTable` and navigate it to other page where i print the value of row content and it get printed successfully. So now what issue may have so it not displaying data but storing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `setLabel()` being called from the Swing Event Dispatching Thread?  If not, this could be causing problems, since most Swing components must only be updated on the EDT.

If `setLabel()` is being called from the EDT, then you have another issue: connecting to a database and executing a long running task in the EDT, which can lock up your UI.  Instead, you should use a `SwingWorker<>` to access the database.

[Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
public class TableTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(TableTest::new);
    }

    private final static String[] COLUMNS = { "x", "x^2", "x^3", "x^4" };
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(COLUMNS, 0);

    TableTest() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Test");
        frame.setSize(600, 300);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTable tbl = new JTable(model);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(tbl), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel btns = new JPanel();
        frame.add(btns, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        btns.add(new JButton(fillTable));

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    Action fillTable = new AbstractAction("Fill Table") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fillTable.setEnabled(false);
            Query query = new Query();
            query.execute();
        }
    };

    class Query extends SwingWorker<Void, String[]> {

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String[]> chunks) {
            for (String[] row : chunks) {
                model.addRow(row);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(400); // Slow database retrieval :-)
                String[] row = new String[4];
                row[0] = Integer.toString(i);
                row[1] = Integer.toString(i * i);
                row[2] = Integer.toString(i * i * i);
                row[3] = Integer.toString(i * i * i * i);
                publish(row);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            fillTable.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```